# WP shortcode returns JSON error despite showing content on website

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've created a custom shortcode to display a specific CPT loop. The code is below:

```
function bundle_grid_shortcode() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'bundle',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row text-center justify-content-center">';
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
    
            $steam = get_field('steam');
            $nx = get_field('nintendo');
            $t1 = get_field('title1');
            $t2 = get_field('title2');
            $percentage = get_field('percentage');
            $setdate = get_field('date');
    
            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="card card-bundle">
                    
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1920/1080" class="img-responsive img-fluid card-img-top" alt="dummy img" />';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </a>

                    <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php 
                            the_title(); 
                        ?>
                    </a>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo '</div></div>';

    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}

add_shortcode('bundle-grid', 'bundle_grid_shortcode');
```

What is awkward is that in general it displays what I wanted. But I'm simply unable to update this page content through Editor/Gutenberg as it drops:

*Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.*

Why is that? I don't understand it.

Comment: What is the response? You should open the browser’s developer tools and check the network tab for the response. It can be anything. And might not be related to the shortcode…

Comment: there is no information about that -.-

Answer (score 0):

To debug what happens when you update a post and get "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response." your best bet is to look at the actual response in the developer tools of your browser.

This is a page that explains how to do that: https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/

Once you have opened the tools for the page you are working at in the backend, go to the network tab. Then click "Update" in the WordPress backend for the post you want to update. You will see a new request being made.

The request url will look something like this: https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/741861?_locale=user

Now when you click the request you will see some extra tabs. See this image:

[image: devtools with Update response]

Now, the thing YOU will see is not a valid json response, but rather a php warning/notice/fatal error. If you can post the response, we can investigate further why you get the invalid json response.